# How to convert n number of images (in jpg format) to .p (pickle) format?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a folder **abc** with images in `.jpg` format.
I need to convert these images to single `xyz.p` (pickled) file. How to pickle these images?

I want to implement something like this:

```
> import pickle  
> training_file = "dataset/train.p"  
> with open(training_file, mode='rb') as f: 
>     train = pickle.load(f)  X_train, y_train = train['features'], train['labels']
```

Comment: Furthermore: What have you tried so far, what doesn't work?

Comment: there is no advantage in saving a pickle file, why would you do that?

Comment: Actually, I want to implement something like this: import pickle


training_file = "dataset/train.p"

with open(training_file, mode='rb') as f:
    train = pickle.load(f)

    
X_train, y_train = train['features'], train['labels']

Comment: Here, I want this train.p contains a particular data (images in folder abc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this :

```
file = open('data.pkl', 'wb') 
pickle.dump(image, file)
file.close()
```